# react hook forms - disappearing default values

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have been having some problems with `react-hook-form` and disappearing defaultValues

So I initiate the useForm with default values, and then get async user location from our API. I want to pre-fill the country based on our user data.

unfortunatelly, after I do that, loose all default values inside `payment` prop.

why is that happening and how can I fix it?

I tried to find some solutions but none seem to help me (`setTimeout`, `useMemo` on defaultValues etc)

```tsx
    const form = useForm<CheckoutFormSteps>({
        defaultValues: {
            team: {
                id: null,
                icon: 'url',
                name: 'someName',
            },
            payment: {
                address1: '',
                address2: '',
                city: '',
                companyName: '',
                paymentMethod: PaymentMethod.CreditCard,
                country: '',
                firstName: '',
                lastName: '',
                phone: '',
                postalCode: '',
                state: '',
                vat_number: '',
            },
        },
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        // some async logic to get user's country
        form.setValue('payment.country', 'US');
        // also tried setTimeout(() => form.setValue('payment.country', 'AU'));
    }, []);
```

then the getValues look like

```
{
  team: {
    id: null,
    icon: 'url',
    name: 'someName',
  },
  payment: {
    country: 'US',
  } // all other payment props are gone
}
```

Comment: form.setValue('payment', {...form.payment, country: 'US'));

Comment: I'm encountering this same problem when I'm not calling setValue. It appears that any field inside of a nested object in a default value field that is not registered by a Component is not retained by react hook form.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
const form = useForm<CheckoutFormSteps>({
        defaultValues: {
            team: {
                id: null,
                icon: 'url',
                name: 'someName',
            },
            payment: {
                address1: '',
                address2: '',
                city: '',
                companyName: '',
                paymentMethod: PaymentMethod.CreditCard,
                country: '',
                firstName: '',
                lastName: '',
                phone: '',
                postalCode: '',
                state: '',
                vat_number: '',
            },
        },
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        // some async logic to get user's country
        form.setValue({
          ...form,
          payment: {
            ...form.payment,
            country: "US"
          }
        });
        // also tried setTimeout(() => form.setValue('payment.country', 'AU'));
    }, []);
```

Whenever you are setting the value, you need to retain the old value as value. For the same reason please use spread operator.